# Android Cannot Resolve Menu Item

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I am working on an RSS Reader for Android and I have encountered a problem when adding a menu item.  I wanted to create an item to refresh the feed manually, but I get an error "Menu.Item cannot be resolved to a type". The error is here:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(Menu.Item item){
    switch (item.getId()) {
    case 0:

        Log.i(tag,"Set RSS Feed");
        return true;
    case 1:
        Log.i(tag,"Refreshing RSS Feed");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The full class is here:

```
package com.CalvaryChapelMelbourne.feedparser;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.content.Intent;

import com.CalvaryChapelMelbourne.feedparser.ShowDescription;

public class RSSReader extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

public final String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "http://app.calvaryccm.com/mobile/android/v1/devos";

public final String tag = "RSSReader";
private RSSFeed feed = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // go get our feed!
    feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);

    // display UI
    UpdateDisplay();

}


private RSSFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
{
    try
    {
        // setup the url
       URL url = new URL(urlToRssFeed);

       // create the factory
       SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
       // create a parser
       SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

       // create the reader (scanner)
       XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
       // instantiate our handler
       RSSHandler theRssHandler = new RSSHandler();
       // assign our handler
       xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);
       // get our data via the url class
       InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
       // perform the synchronous parse           
       xmlreader.parse(is);
       // get the results - should be a fully populated RSSFeed instance, or null on error
       return theRssHandler.getFeed();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        // if we have a problem, simply return null
        return null;
    }
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0,0,"Choose RSS Feed");
    menu.add(0,1,"Refresh");
    Log.i(tag,"onCreateOptionsMenu");
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(Menu.Item item){
    switch (item.getId()) {
    case 0:

        Log.i(tag,"Set RSS Feed");
        return true;
    case 1:
        Log.i(tag,"Refreshing RSS Feed");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


private void UpdateDisplay()
{
    TextView feedtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
    TextView feedpubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
    ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);


    if (feed == null)
    {
        feedtitle.setText("No RSS Feed Available");
        return;
    }

    feedtitle.setText(feed.getTitle());
    feedpubdate.setText(feed.getPubDate());

    ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems());

    itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

    itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    itemlist.setSelection(0);

}


 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {
     Log.i(tag,"item clicked! [" + feed.getItem(position).getTitle() + "]");

     Intent itemintent = new Intent(this,ShowDescription.class);

     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("title", feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
     b.putString("description", feed.getItem(position).getDescription());
     b.putString("link", feed.getItem(position).getLink());
     b.putString("pubdate", feed.getItem(position).getPubDate());

     itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

     startSubActivity(itemintent,0);
 }

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter in onOptionsItemSelected should be MenuItem, not Menu.Item. Simply remove the dot and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `MenuItem`, not `Menu.Item`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `Menu.Item` to `MenuItem`